# how to minise set_fact with lookup password

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create passwords variables with `lookup('password')` and trying to respect this specific policy: `foOBar1_FoO2Bar_3BarFoo` (for exemple)

**regex**: 7 characters from "`digits,ascii_lowercase,ascii_uppercase`" repeated 2 two, separated by `'_'` character

I wrote this:

```yaml
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    password_length: "7"
    password_spec_str: "digits,ascii_lowercase,ascii_uppercase"
  tasks:
  - name: "Generate 2 randoms passwords"
    set_fact:
      FirstPass: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=' ~ password_length ~ ' chars=' ~ password_spec_str ) + '_' + lookup('password', '/dev/null length=' ~ password_length ~ ' chars=' ~ password_spec_str ) + '_' + lookup('password', '/dev/null length=' ~ password_length ~ ' chars=' ~ password_spec_str ) }}"
      SecondPass: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=' ~ password_length ~ ' chars=' ~ password_spec_str ) + '_' + lookup('password', '/dev/null length=' ~ password_length ~ ' chars=' ~ password_spec_str ) + '_' + lookup('password', '/dev/null length=' ~ password_length ~ ' chars=' ~ password_spec_str ) }}"

...
```

Results :

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Generate 2 randoms passwords] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
mardi 26 juillet 2022  16:26:05 +0200 (0:00:00.020)       0:00:00.020 *********
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    FirstPass: WqUjDBf_NDPX5zQ_YRnhaAP
    SecondPass: RGBkrIM_t9zS8tB_iCFrp3E

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
```

So the result suits me perfectly, but not the way to write that..

Does anyone have another idea to 'beautify' this set_fact ?

Thanks !

Comment: So, you would like not to have `lookup('password' ...` three times in one line, but stay with the produced result. Would a `loop` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So the result suits me perfectly, but not the way to write that. Does anyone have another idea to 'beautify' this `set_fact` ?*

If

- neither the password lookup plugin nor an other plugin is producing the output you are looking for
- and you like to simplify the logic of password generation

you may need to work with characters and strings.

You could generate a longer temporary random string and construct the final string from it. To do so

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    password_length: "22" # character for one password excluding delimiter counting from 1
    password_spec_str: "digits,ascii_lowercase,ascii_uppercase"
    d: '_' # delimiter

  tasks:

  - name: "Generate 2 randoms passwords"
    set_fact:
      FirstPass: "{{ _pwd[:7] + d + _pwd[7:14] + d + _pwd[-7:] }}"
      SecondPass: "{{ _pwd[:7] + d + _pwd[7:14] + d + _pwd[-7:] }}"
    vars:
      _pwd: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=' ~ password_length ~ ' chars=' ~ password_spec_str ) }}"

  - name: Show passwords
    debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ FirstPass }}"
        - "{{ SecondPass }}"
```

In this case [accessing elements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) with [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/) was used, as well [task vars (only for the task)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#ansible-variable-precedence) resulting into an output in example of

```yaml
TASK [Show passwords] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - F3lH5SV_heNTbTO_4YFAyOw
  - O8BucxG_VBDTHaO_6vzCV80
```

One advantage of the approach is that the lookup plugin is called only twice instead of six times before. An other one is that it is shorter and easier to read, the lookup plugin call is just written ones instead of six times before.

---

Depending on the Ansible version your are on, you could enhance your case with [`random_words` lookup – Return a number of random words](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/random_words_lookup.html)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Generate words
    debug:
      var: lookup('random_words', numwords=3, delimiter='_', case='random')
```

**Further Reading**

- [XKCD password generator](https://github.com/redacted/XKCD-password-generator)

Comment: random_words generate "predictive" words, here I want to completly mix characters and digits on parts of the passwords randomly